# Use mirror to see every angle around me

Tags: visible-light, reflection

An applied physics question: How can I setup a mirror all around an arm wrestling  table so I can see all angles of what I'm doing?

The arm wresting table looks like this

[image]

With the wrestlers on table looks like

[image]

Comment: Where did the answers and comments go?